# Apache Spark class for int array key in Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm using multiple integers as a key in Spark.  Is there an existing class in Apache Spark that has this functionality so I don't need to implement hashCode, etc?  This is in Java and not Scala.

```
public class MultiIntKey
{
  public int key1;
  public int key2;
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Do your keys contain a small, fixed number of integers (e.g. 3 integers) or do you need to support arbitrary-sized arrays of ints?

Comment: @Josh right now, just 2 ints.  But also expecting 3 ints.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to take a look at Java tuples or Scala where tuples are part of std library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javatuples</groupId>
    <artifactId>javatuples</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[javatuples](http://www.javatuples.org) offers you tuple classes from one to ten elements + they all have equals + hashcode. They all immutable. Your version is mutable btw, and it's really bad practice for class used as key.

```
Unit<A> (1 element)
Pair<A,B> (2 elements)
Triplet<A,B,C> (3 elements)
Quartet<A,B,C,D> (4 elements)
Quintet<A,B,C,D,E> (5 elements)
Sextet<A,B,C,D,E,F> (6 elements)
Septet<A,B,C,D,E,F,G> (7 elements)
Octet<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H> (8 elements)
Ennead<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I> (9 elements)
Decade<A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J> (10 elements)
```

Comment: I was thinking CustomerDateKey is more readable than Pair<Integer, Integer>?  Thanks.

Comment: +1 to using Scala tuples, since Spark already has a transitive dependency on the Scala standard library (so it's one less dependency).